# Unable to compare Date value returned from SOQL within next SOQL where clause date field

Tags: apex, soql

Not able to compare dates returned from one SOQL as a list into another SOQL's where clause:

ApexCode to store all date data into list:

```
List<Account> a = [SELECT ID, FIRSTNAME,PersonContactId,PersonBirthdate FROM ACCOUNT];
 List<Date> dob = new List<Date>();
 for(Account r: a){
  dob.add(r.PersonBirthdate);
 }
```

ApexCode with another:

```
List<Account> b = [SELECT ID, FIRSTNAME,PersonContactId,PersonBirthdate FROM ACCOUNT WHERe PersonBirthdate IN: dob];
```

**No data returned**

Comment: Can you print to know what is the size of dob list?

Comment: How does it matter?

Comment: As this type of query works for me at my DE

Comment: According to the documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm) "value of the IN or NOT IN operator in WHERE clauses, allowing filtering on a dynamic set of values. Note that this is of particular use with a list of IDs or Strings, though it works with lists of any type". Also note "The year portion of the PersonBirthDate field is ignored in filter criteria, including report filters, list view filters, and SOQL queries" (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm)